# Get everybody "rustled" in the place

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a comment that came out of a discussion on McDonalds:

> I remember working at McHell for over 2 years. 25 cars in the Drive-Thru was nothing. The worst part was a semi-full lobby/Drive-Thru and then a buss pulls in. That shit would get everybody rustled in the place... Shit being thrown everywhere, people yelling. Good times.

What does *rustle* mean when he says the buss would get everybody rustled in the place? I couldn't find a definition in the dictionaries that's appropriate to the context. And I'm assuming he made a typo and meant bus instead of buss?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the jimmies that are being rustled?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90246/what-are-the-jimmies-that-are-being-rustled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a shortened form of *rustle one's jimmies*. Urban Dictionary is often useful for this sort of slang in forum/group posts.

> [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rustle+my+jimmies)
>
> “That Really Rustled My Jimmies” is an expression that is used to convey feelings of discontent or discomfort in response to someone else’s post in imageboards and discussion forums, most notably on 4chan. To rustle one's jimmies means to make someone discontent or to bother someone.

*Rustled* in the context you quote (in a fast-food outlet) simply means *made unhappy, discontented, dicomfited, disturbed, annoyed, anxious...*

[And he almost certainly does mean *bus*. *Buss* is a ship.]

Comment: Funny I have never seen a bus pulled in the drive-thru. I'm not sure if it could even go through the roadway lol.

Comment: He doesn't say the bus pulled in *at the drive-through*, just that it pulled in. "Pulled in" just means "arrived" or "stopped there". For example we say a train "pulled in" to the station.

Comment: @MετάEd Oh I thought, because of the many orders from the passengers in the bus that's what made the staffs rustle.

Comment: @Theo Oh, that's true, but the passengers would have disembarked and gone in to the place rather than ordering through the drive-through window.

Comment: @MετάEd Damn I'm slow :smh: